# SHA-1 hash of a hierarchical folder

Tags: security, authentication, cryptography, certificate, x509certificate

I have a hierarchical folder structure with the root folder containing a few sub-folders with file contents and a few root folder files. I would like to generate a signature for the hierarchical folder contents.

Plan is to generate a SHA-1 hash of the hierarchical folder contents. A tool (which I do not know as of yet) must recursively pick stuff from each of the sub-folders and also consider the root files before generating a cumulative hash of the contents. Idea is to then encrypt this cumulative hash using a private key and place this signature in the root folder.

Is this possible? Can OpenSSL or any other tool do this?

Comment: Don't "encrypt using a private key". Use a dedicated signature operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you need to ask is: what do you want to protect with the signature? the content of every file? The path of the files? The addition or removal of some files? The solution adopted by Debian to sign the package repository is the following:

1. create a text file at the top level of the directory containing the list of files in the directory. For each file, add the digest value of the file content.

   For instance:

   ```
   /root/dir1/file1.bin         sha1:928a2c3350e2894a5614e88c9e3bfa03c3c19b43
   /root/dir1/file2.bin         sha1:13945d6f641725b091d5fd936da61084da3d8f89
   /root/dir2/file1.bin         sha1:614dbf0fe42e76bc52b539a27cdb6838162130b5
   /root/dir2/subdir/file3.bin  sha1:a0e96d0478c19273783e643a24ef1ea7cb432a48
   ```
2. Sign this file with openssl:

   `openssl dgst -sha1 -sign privateKey.pem file.txt > file.txt.sig`

Comment: This is of course a correct solution. I would create the text file/signature in a different location than the one that you are hashing, and I would try and opt for either SHA-256 or SHA-512 and possibly RSA-PSS, but the general idea is good (and there are many protocols that use the same mechanism).

Comment: Oh, and `find . -type f -print0  | xargs -0 sha1sum`, found [here](http://superuser.com/questions/458326/sha1sum-for-a-directory-of-directories/458356#458356). Note that programming some kind of sorting (to find mismatches) and comparison function may be trickier.

Answer (score 1):

It seems possible.
I would take a hash (why SHA-1 and not SHA-256? search in Wikipedia SHA-1) on each file in a folder. Concatenate the hashes by the names of the files (lexicographically), and calculate the hash for the folder by a hash on the concatenated files hashes.
You can do it recursively.

Another option (although it seems more complicated) is to refer all the folders as one huge file: you can scan your folder in deterministic way (like DFS), and just sign on the data as one (very big) structured file.

I'm sure you can find libraries and code for calculating the hash function on a file.
For signing, you just need a pair of private and public key (RSA or El-Gamal for example).
You sign by "encrypting" your code with your private key.

So if OpenSSL provides you such a keys pair - you probably can use it.